# Bind WPF conrol size to window size

Tags: wpf, binding, converters

I am trying to bind a `TabControl` to the `size` of the `MainWindow` in `WPF`. I have done it very easily, but the problem is with padding or margin.

If I just set the both with the same size during the window `resize`, then the `TabControl` hangs off the right side of the window by it's border. I have tried playing with padding and margin of the `TabControl` with no effect on it's over flow of the window.

Should I use a custom converter? My skill with them is pretty novice and am not sure how I would work a two way converter for these properties.

Comment: Did you try to change all the paddings and margins in the TabControl's control template?

Comment: What's wrong with just using a `Grid` or `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`?

Comment: Setting the Alignments to Stretch did it for me, thank you for your help, Sheridan. I am brand new to WPF. Daniel, I did work with padding and margin but it didn't help with the overflow.

Comment: @Sheridan, that's good for an answer.